# What do these cut commands mean?

Tags: linux, command-line

What do these successive `cut` commands do?

```
cut -f2 -d'"' | cut -f1 -d':'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means take the second field (`-f2`) as separated by double quote marks (`-d'"'`, which the shell parses to `-d'` before running cut) , and then the first field (`-f1`) of that as separated by colons (`-d:`).

For instance, `Phil Miller"developer:junior` will be processed to `developer`. This is a very contrived example, and it would be useful to see what is actually being used as input to that pipeline.

Comment: Note that if the line does not start with a quote, this will take what you'd read as the first quoted string in the line, while if it does start with a quote, it'll grab what's after the second quote.

Comment: can we get the count of cuts,  generated by "cut" command @Novelocrat

Answer (score 4):

The `-f` is the *field specifier* and the `-d` is the *delimiter*.

The command above says to first cut the line up using `"` as the delimiter, and return back the 2nd field(`-f2`).

The second command cuts up that result using the `:` delimiter, and returns back the 1st field(`-f1`).

Cut is useful for parsing through csv-like files, which have potentially embedded delimiters.